# Break in loops in R

Tags: r

Hey everyone I have a question. My professor said the output of the following code will be `1 2 3 4` but on console it shows

```
[1]1
[1]2
[1]3
[1]4
```

```
i <- 1
while(i <= 10)
{
if(i %% 5==0){
break
}
print(i)
i <- i + 1
}
```

Can someone please help me!

Comment: Welcome to R! The `[1]` is R's way of saying that you are printing a vector, and the "thing" immediately next to the `[1]` is the vector's first entry. R does not have "scalars", the smallest data structure it has is a vector, so a number (e.g., `3.14`) is a vector of length 1. If you type in `1<ret>` and then `2<ret>`, you'll see `[1] 1` and then `[1] 2`, which is R's way of saying that the return-value of your first expression is a vector, length-1, with a `1` in it; ditto with the `2`.

Comment: If you want \*just\* what you said, then replace `print(i)` with `cat(i, "")` (yes, that's an empty string, not a space, read `?cat` and find `sep=`), then after the last brace add `cat("\n")`, and you'll get your literal output (for whatever it's worth).

Comment: omg! thanks a lot

Comment: This kind of material is usually covered in tutorials for the language; if your professor is not providing one (a missed teaching opportunity), then I strongly suggest you will gain big dividends by doing as much of one or two as you can carve time out to do. Unfortunately I don't know any off the top of my head, but https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/index.htm and https://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction come up high in my google search, perhaps they're good enough. (Not knowing this much about R will make many other things you'll need to do that much harder, no doubt.)